# Issue with Ajax open function in google chrome 28.0.1500.72 and later

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, asynchronous

I think I found an issue where ajax open functions are not behaving properly in google chrome after the version 28.0.1500.72 update. This issue was originally found using an embedded webserver as the server, but I have been able to reproduce it on an apache webserver as well.

The issue occurs when I call ajaxObject.open("GET","URL",true). This usually works, however sometimes the client pc running the javascript will not issue a GET request for the url(This has been confirmed using wireshark). At this point ajaxObject.readyState changes from 1 to 2 to 4 as if it sent the request properly and received a response. This issue did not occur with chrome previously, and is not an issue on IE or firefox.  Interestingly, on a successful call, ajaxObject.readyState goes from 1, to 2, to 3, to 4.

We've hard coded the headers on our embedded webserver to not cache the requested page fetched via ajax, as we need to request the page over and over again and refresh it's contents. To duplicate this functionality on apache, I added:

```
<FilesMatch ".(shtml|html|js|css)$"> 
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

to the httdp-conf file.

The following is the html page that I am able to reproduce the issue on.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function newAjaxObject() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try {           // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {   // Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser does not support Javascript/AJAX!  Please upgrade your browser.");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function getStatus() {
    var ajaxStatus = newAjaxObject();

    ajaxStatus.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(ajaxStatus.readyState==4) {
          eval('var tester =' + ajaxStatus.responseText);
          queueStatusUpdate();  
        }
    }
    ajaxStatus.open("GET","status.shtml",true);
    ajaxStatus.send(null);
}

// Wait 'timeDelay' milliseconds before requesting an update
var timeDelay = 100;
function queueStatusUpdate() {
    setTimeout('getStatus()',timeDelay);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="queueStatusUpdate();">

</body>
</html>
```

This is the response text that should be in the status.shtml page:

```
{"status":"Valid Data"}
```

[image: working breakpoint]
[image: working request]

Using the network tab in the chrome debugger, navigate to the page and hit refresh until you see that it stops requesting status.shtml and an error has been thrown.

[image: no request sent]
[image: breakpoint with status 0]

I believe this is an issue with Chrome, but thought I'd post it here before submitting it as a bug for them just in case I am missing something simple.

Also, changing from an asynchronous request to a synchronous request fixes the issue, but that is not the route I want to take.

Thanks !

Comment: *Which* error does get thrown, and where?

Comment: when are you calling tester.status?

Comment: The error gets thrown when eval('var tester =' + ajaxStatus.responseText); is called because ajaxStatus.responseText is blank. Unexpected end of input is the error thrown. The error is not what I am worried about though, it should never get into this chunk of code because it never actually issues a GET request or receives a reply for status.shtml. tester is only there to illustrate the issue I am not interested in using it for anything.

Comment: You mean you're refreshing the page until `ajaxStatus.responseText` is blank for a request?

Comment: Please do a `console.log(ajaxStatus.status)`

Comment: I attempted to upload a few pictures in order to illustrate what is happening better but I can't post pictures because I dont have enough reputation. However to answer you question, when this works as it should console.log(ajaxStatus.status) is 200. When the failure happens it is undefined. The issue is that sometimes when ajaxStatus.open("GET","status.shtml",true); is called, the client does not fire off a GET request for the page, but ajaxStatus.readyState still increments to 4 even though the page request was never made.

Comment: Can you upload the pictures to some image hosters and link them?

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/jYYxrx8.png) and [link](http://i.imgur.com/dqgOp7V.png) illustrate the success case. The GET request for status.html is made and handled correctly. [link](http://i.imgur.com/hCMLgbD.png) and [link](http://i.imgur.com/o0v9sEj.png) illustrate the failure mode when a GET request for status.html is not made, but the script still runs as if it had been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same Chrome bug and I was able to confirm it with your code. The workaround I found was to append a random parameter to the URL (something like ?rand=XYZ, to make the URL unique) and just re-try the original AJAX request with the new URL.

Based on my testing, here is some information that might be helpful:

- I was able to reproduce the bug on the latest stable version of Chrome: 28.0.1500.95
- I was only able to reproduce the bug on the Windows version. I also tested the same version of Chrome on OSX and I was unable to reproduce it there.
- The bug appears when an AJAX request is interrupted by leaving the page and then persists for the entire life of that tab (this is why it's important to refresh the test page until the bug shows up). Once a request fails, all future requests for that resource in the same tab will fail, even if the page is reloaded.

Comment: Yes this does fix the issue. Unfortunately changing the client code is not really an option at this point so hopefully google will fix this problem. But if anyone else is experiencing a similar problem then this solution does fix it.